# Do floating bar graphs exist in matlab?

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a simple bar graph that would essentially look like the following horrible ASCII rendering:

```
Y
| ----------
|     ---
|         -----
| --
| -------
|______________ X
  5  6  7  8 9
```

Is this possible? I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [`JFreeChart`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jfreechart-graphs-and-gauges/). By the way this plot is called a [**Gantt Chart**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know exactly the coordinates of the desired bars in the graph, and the width of each bar line, you can do somthing like that:

```
a=[5 10; 5 23; 7 13; 6 18];      % each pair is a start point of bar 
L=0.1;                           %Bar width

for i=1:size(a,1)
    plot([a(i,1) a(i,1)+L], [a(i,2) a(i,2)])
    hold on
    ylim([ 9 24])
end
```

where in `a` you put the coordinates, and `L` is the bar length.

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't come to that, but that works! thanks!