# Plotting arrays using a grouped horizontal bar graph

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to generate a graph that should look similar to:
[image]

My arrays are:

```
Array4:[Nan;Nan;.......;20;21;22;23;24;..........60]
Array3:[[Nan;Nan;.......;20;21;22;23;24;..........60]
Array2:[0;1;2;3;4;5;6;Nan;Nan;Nan;Nan;17;18;.....60]
Array1:[0;1;2;3;4;5;6;Nan;Nan;Nan;Nan;17;18;.....60]
```

I cannot find the right way to group my arrays in order to plot them in the way shown on the above graph.
I tried using the following function explained in: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/barh.html

```
barh(1:numel(x),y,'hist')
```

where `y=[Array1,Array2;Array3,Array4]` and `x={'1m';'2m';'3m';......'60m'}`

but it does not work.

Comment: try to set `y = [Array1;Array2;Array3;Array4]` and also provide any error that matlab returns.

Comment: @GameOfThrows. I tried y=[Array1;Array2;Array3;Array4] but I get the following  error: "X must be the same length as Y".

Comment: it means that the length of Array 1 to 4 needs to be the same, you will need to pad with NaN or Zeros so that they are the same length.

Comment: @GameOfThrows: All arrays have the same length. All of them are 60x1 double arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why Your Current Approach Isn't Working**

Your intuition makes sense to me, but the `barh` function you are using doesn't work the way you think it does. Specifically, you are interpreting the meaning of the `x` and `y` inputs to that function incorrectly. Those are inputs are constant values, not entire axes. The first `y` input refers to the end-point of the bar that stretches horizontally from `x = 0` and the first `x` input refers to location on the y-axis of the horizontal bar. To illustrate what I mean, I've provided the below horizontal bar graph:
[image: Simple MATLAB-generated Horizontal Bar Graph]

You can find this same picture in the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/barh.html) of the MATLAB `barh` function. The code used to generate this bar graph is also given in the documentation, shown below:

```
x = 1900:10:2000;
y = [57,91,105,123,131,150,...
 170,203,226.5,249,281.4];
figure;
barh(x, y);
```

The individual elements of the `x` array, rather confusingly, show up on the y-axis as the starting locations of each bar. The *corresponding* elements of the `y` array are the lengths of each bar. This is the reason that the arrays must be the same length, and this illustrates that they are not specifications of the x and y axes as one might intuitively believe.

**An Approach To Solve Your Problem**

First things first, the easiest approach is to do this manually with the `plot` function and a set of lines that represent floating bars. Consult the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) for the `plot` function if you'd like to plot the lines with some sort of color coordination in mind - the code I present (modified version of [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460394/do-floating-bar-graphs-exist-in-matlab)) just switches the color of the floating bars between red and blue. I tried to comment the code so that the purpose of each variable is clear. The code I present below matches the floating bar graph that you want to be plotted, if you are alright with replacing thick floating bars with 2D lines floating on a plot.

I used the data that you gave in your question to specify the floating horizontal bars that this script would output - a screenshot is shown below the code. `Array1 & Array2:[0;1;2;3;4;5;6;Nan;Nan;Nan;Nan;17;18;.....60]`, these arrays go from 0 to 6 (length = 6) and 17 to 60 (length = 60 - 17 = 43). Because there is a "discontinuity" of sorts from 7 to 16, I have to define two floating bars for each array. Hence, the first four values in my length array are `[6, 6, 43, 43]`. Where the first 6 and the first 43 correspond to `Array1` and the second 6 and the second 43 correspond to `Array2`. Recognizing this "discontinuity", the starting point of the first floating bar for `Array1` and `Array2` is `x = 0` and the starting point of the second floating bar for `Array1` and `Array2` is `x = 7`. Putting that all together, you arrive at the x-coordinates for the first four points in the `floating_bars` array, `[0 0; 0 1.5; 17 0; 17 1.5]`. The y-coordinates in this array only serve to distinguish `Array1`, `Array2`, and so on from each other.

*Code:*

```
floating_bars=[0 0; 0 1.5; 17 0; 17 1.5; 20 6; 20 7.5]; % Each row is the [x,y] coordinate pair of the starting point for the floating bar
L=[6, 6, 43, 43, 40, 40]; % Length of each consecutive bar
thickness = 0.75;

figure;
    for i=1:size(floating_bars,1)
        curr_thickness = 0;
        % It is aesthetically pleasing to have thicker bars, this makes the plot look for like the grouped horizontal bar graph that you want
        while (curr_thickness < thickness)
            % Each bar group has two bars; set the first to be red, the second to be blue (i.e., even index means red bar, odd index means blue bar)
            if mod(i, 2)
                plot([floating_bars(i,1), floating_bars(i,1)+L(i)], [floating_bars(i,2) + curr_thickness, floating_bars(i,2) + curr_thickness], 'r')
            else
                plot([floating_bars(i,1), floating_bars(i,1)+L(i)], [floating_bars(i,2) + curr_thickness, floating_bars(i,2) + curr_thickness], 'b')
            end
        curr_thickness = curr_thickness + 0.05;
        hold on % Make sure that plotting the current floating bar does not overwrite previous float bars that have already been plotted
    end
end
ylim([ -10 30]) % Set the y-axis limits so that you can see more clearly the floating bars that would have rested right on the x-axis (y = 0)
```

*Output:*

[image: Resulting Floating Bar Graph]

**How Do I Do This With the `barh` Function?**

The short answer is that you'd have to modify the function manually. Someone has already done this with one of the bar graph plotting functions provided by MATLAB, `bar3`. The logic implemented in this [modified `bar3` function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93135-how-can-i-make-floating-bar-graphs-using-bar3-command-in-matlab-7-5-r2007b) can be re-applied for your purposes if you read their `barNew.m` function and tweak it a bit. If you'd like a pointer as to where to start, I'd suggest looking at how they specify z-axis minimum and maximums for their floating bars on the plot, and apply that same logic to specify x-axis minimum and maximums for your floating bars in your 2D case.

I hope this helps, happy coding! :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. On  your first approach,  would it be possible to group these floating bars in pairs as it appears on the graph I posted?. I am ok with replacing thick floating bars with 2D floating lines, however, grouping them in pairs is quite important for me.

Comment: Sorry, I have just realised that you already did it (I think). As there is so much space in between the lines I did not realised that you already tried to group them. Is this correct?

Comment: @Sarah I decided to space each line 5 units away from the next set of lines. If you'd like, you could change the increment in the y-coordinate of the points I specify in `floating_bars` to something smaller for lines that are paired together and keep it significantly larger for lines that aren't supposed to be paired. I will update the code I provide to reflect the solution I am trying to explain in words.

Comment: Did my edits to the answer help you? If so, I'd greatly appreciate it if you accepted my answer. If it didn't, could you explain what further questions you have? Thank you!

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, I have understood your example and I have been trying to figure out for a long time how to use your example with my data. However, I do not know how could I calculate the length of each consecutive bar with data from arrays as opposed to standard lengths.

Comment: I got the numbers I chose for the two arrays I define from the arrays you showed in your question. By *calculate the length of each consecutive bar with data from arrays*, I presume you mean find the lengths programmatically for any given array (otherwise, length is already specified in an array...). If that is the case, then I'd suggest adding some logic in your code to scan the contents of each array you plan on providing as input that will: 1) find the start and end point and 2) find any discontinuities so you know to create a new floating bar.

Comment: Ok, I see now that you have calculated the lengths of each consecutive bar taking into account the discontinuities and by differentiating the end point and the starting point of each bar (e.g. for Array1: 6-0=0 and 60-17=43.

Comment: I would have to definitely find a way to calculate the lengths from the arrays programmatically as the arrays I have posted in this example are 60x1 doubles but I usually have much longer arrays.

Comment: This approach makes sense to me now, however I thought perhaps there was an easier approach?, like plotting the arrays using a simple hold on plot(1:numel(x),Array1) plot(1:numel(x),Array2) plot(1:numel(x),Array3) plot(1:numel(x),Array4)  hold off and including some extra code to group somehow Array1 with Array2 and Array3 with Array4?

Comment: Perhaps I can use your for loop code to group my plot(1:numel(x),Arrays) in the same way?. Not sure how right now.

Comment: I'd love to help, but the questions you're asking me in these comments are reaching well beyond the scope of your original question. Answering this new question would be too much for me to do completely in just comments. I think that you have the tools available in this answer and our healthy exchange in the comments to figure out how to implement this new feature. Best of luck!

Comment: Ok, I have accepted your answer as your explained method generates the graph I was looking for. However, this method is not enough for me as I was looking for a more programmatic solution. You are right saying I could design a function to programmaticaly calculate the lengths of each discontinuity in the arrays, but I found doing that quite difficult and confusing so I came up with another solution that I am going to post here soon.

Comment: That's splendid! I look forward to see what programmatic solution you came up with. Two minds working to solve a problem is always better than one :)

Answer (score 0):

I explain here my approach to generate these type of graphs. Not sure if it is the best but it works and there is no need to do anything manually. I came up with this solution based on the following Vladislav Martin's explained fact: "The y-coordinates in this array only serve to distinguish Array1, Array2, and so on from each other".

My original arrays are:

```
Array4=[Nan....;20;21;22;23;24;..........60]
Array3=[Nan....;20;21;22;23;24;..........60]
Array2=[0;1;2;3;4;5;6;Nan;Nan;Nan;Nan;17;18;.....60]
Array1=[0;1;2;3;4;5;6;Nan;Nan;Nan;Nan;17;18;.....60]

x={'0m';'1m';'2m';'3m';'4m';....'60m'}
```

The values contained in these arrays make reference to the x-axis on the graph. In order to make the things more simple and to avoid having to code a function to determine the length for each discontinuity in the arrays, I replace these values for y-axis position values. Basically I give to Array1 y-axis position values of 0 and to Array2 0+0.02=0.02. To Array3 I give y-axis position values of 0.5 and to Array4 0.5+0.02=0.52. In this way, Array2 will be plotted on the graph closer to Array1 which will form the first group and Array4 closer to Array3 which will form the second group.

```
Datatable=table(Array1,Array2,Array3,Array4);

cont1=0;
cont2=0.02;

for col=1:2:size(Datatable,2)

   col2=col+1;   

   for row=1:size(Datatable,1)

      if isnan(Datatable{row,col})==0   % For first array in the group: If the value is not nan, I replace it for the corresponnding cont1 value
         Datatable{row,col}=cont1;
      end 

      if isnan(Datatable{row,col2})==0  % For second array in the group: If the value is not nan, I replace it for the corresponnding cont2 value
         Datatable{row,col2}=cont2;
      end  

   end

   cont1=cont1+0.5;

   cont2=cont2+0.5;

end
```

The result of the above code will be a table like the following:

[image]

And now I plot the Arrays using 2D floating lines:

```
figure

for array=1:2:size(Datatable,2)

    FirstPair=cell2mat(table2cell(Datatable(:,array)));
    SecondPair=cell2mat(table2cell(Datatable(:,array+1)));

    hold on
    plot(1:numel(x),FirstPair,'r','Linewidth',6) 
    plot(1:numel(x),SecondPair,'b','Linewidth',6) 
    hold off

end

   set(gca,'xticklabel',x)
```

And this will generate the following graph:

[image]